# MacOS on VMWare: 100% disk usage for no reason

Tags: macos, hard-drive, virtual-machine

I use a VM on VMware Fusion environment with macOS as guest OS on a macOS host OS.

The VM has installed only xCode and beamoff (an applet which tune graphic performance severely impaired by the 128MB vRAM constraint).

It often reports that, for apparently no reason, the disk usage raise up to 100% for about 30-40 minutes, making the machine completely unusable. Also restarting the machine usually does not work because the spike begin again just after the reboot.

How could I check what is happening? Is this a common issue? Any tips to solve it?

The VM runs on HDD, with dedicated 8GB ram and 2c/4th i7 atm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. 
As you can see I didn't mention the HW it is running on. 
If you take a look, you can see that on MacOs there is the VMWare Workstation Fusion edition which allows VMs. 

As I am developing for Mac, it is useful to me to have virtual clients on my machine. 

Too bad i had to explain it before receiving any help

Comment: VMWare Workstation is Windows software. VMWare Fusion is Mac. Had you started with the correct product name there may have been less confusion.

Comment: Still very helpful. Do you pass your day lurking for question which may appears uncorrectly formatted just to close them? I'm trying to work damn.

Comment: One thing you'll quickly discover here is that a bad attitude gets you no favours. You'll note someone has already kindly edited the question to make it more answerable.

Comment: Here's perhaps the most recent discussion on Hackintosh in the Meta: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12050/revisit-the-hackintosh-policy Also, to echo @Tetsujin, getting prickly is a very good way to get your question closed. This is a community, and communities require a certain amount of working together. Tetsujin gave a good reason, and you are free to discuss that in a mature manner. Your ascerbic and passive-aggressive responses may be factually correct, but their style makes then unacceptable within a healthy community.